# F# creating generic function with generic units of measure

Tags: generics, f#, units-of-measurement

I feel like I may be fighting the way F# wants to think about types and units of measure but I wanted to ask this question in case I'm missing something obvious. I am using types and units of measure as a way to make sure all operations have type alignment. I am wanting to define a generic `tryDivide` function which will taking matching types but I am running around in circles trying to make it work Here is the non-generic version that works:

```
[<Measure>] type USD (* US Dollars *)

let tryDivide a b =
    match b > 0M with
    | true -> a / b |> decimal |> Some
    | false -> None


type Cost = decimal<USD>

module Cost =
    let create v : Cost =
        v * 1M<USD>

    let tryDivide (a:Cost) (b:Cost) =
        tryDivide (decimal a) (decimal b)

let costA = Cost.create 10M
let costB = Cost.create 20M

let ratio = Cost.tryDivide costA costB
```

The problem is that I have to define a `tryDivide` function for each type (Ex: `Cost.tryDivide`). Is there some way to make the top level `tryDivide` function generic for types and units of measure? Ideally it would take any type which is really just a `decimal<'u>` which has units of measure. I have tried various function signatures but nothing works. If I do something like the following it restricts the inputs to `int`

```
let tryDivide (a: 'u) (b: 'u) =
    let x = (decimal a)
    let y = (decimal b)
    match y > 0M with
    | true -> x / y |> decimal |> Some
    | false -> None
```

If my thought process is fundamentally wrong, I would love to hear it. I hand code a `tryDivide` for each type, that just seems inefficient.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer right after. You need to make the `b > 0M` generic on units. To do this you need to open the `Microsoft.FSharp.Core.LanguagePrimitives` module and use the `DecimalWithMeasure` function. Here is the new version of the `tryDivide` function:

```
let tryDivide a b =
    match b > (DecimalWithMeasure 0M) with
    | true -> a / b |> Some
    | false -> None
```